# need to run DIR command and return true or false if path exists

Tags: cmd, dir, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have a DFS namespace url and want rom time to time to test from another server that uses those resources is access to namespace is permitted.

Manually from CMD I would do something like `dir "\\namespaceURL"` and the results will be the files and dirs from that namespace.

I just want to configure an alert and trigger a task when the dir command does not return anything. I am thinking at something like:

```
If (dir "\\namespaceURL" is ok) echo "available" else echo "not-available"
```

Can you guys have a look over this and let me know your thoughts?

Comment: If I get it right, I think you could use `if exist \namespaceURL\.`...

Comment: well, a;ready tried with if exist but I couldn't make it work with a namespace URL,

Comment: i get the error: namespaceURL was unexpected at this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if exist` should be the way to go, but if you want to use `dir`, here is the syntax:

```
dir "\\namespaceURL" >nul 2>&1 && (echo found) || (echo no access)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephan. i'll give it a try. How would the if exist version look like for the same case?

Comment: this could be the version with IfExist
if exist "\\namespaceURL" (echo found) else (echo not_found)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Does anyone knows if there could be a way to have the same results using a powershell script?